# Excel Format using functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I am trying to create a custom format (or conditional format) in Excel that would take a 3 digit number and display a text (conditional on the first digit) concatenated with the last 2 digits. I can do this in a separate column (see picture below), but would prefer to do it as a format on the original data. Here's a screenshot doing it with a formula in a separate column. (First digit will always be either 1, 2, or 3).

[image: Screen Shot of Spreadsheeet with formula to turn into format]

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, you're not trying to "format" the contents.  The difference is, formats are bi-directional.  Meaning, I can type in 1/2/2018 or jan 2 2018 or 2018-2-1, and all three would be understood as a date, and can be translated back & forth freely.

Without relying on macros using VBA, (which is a whole other discussion outside scope of what can/should be discussed here) your options are exceptionally limited.

As a quick & dirty solution, you could simply hide the column containing the actual numbers (column A), and that would only leave the formatted column (B).  Just be warned, that you cannot type in data in the 2nd column and have it populate the first.